# How can i add a search bar in google maps v2 with a) suggestions b)drop down menu

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am building a taxi app similar to Uber.. I am using Android Studio and implementing code in Java. Java servlets and jsps for the server side with My sql as the DB.
Any links or code with my mentioned requirement would be of great help.

I want a search bar with suggestions with a drop down menu of pickup and drop off locations like the one in Uber app.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what problems do you have with a `SearchView`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: what kind of problems do you have with a `SearchView`?

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/

Comment: I am trying to implement this tutorial in my app.. I want to add a drop down menu how can i do that..?

Comment: see `SearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Create new activity and get input from user or use static input in order to query from google for nearby places

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?");
sb.append("query=" + "Your input OR user input";
sb.append("&key=You Api key here");

PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
```

and create a `PlacesTask` class

```
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String data = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

And then create Paresetask

```
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            PlacesJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlacesJSONParser();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
            if (customSearch) {
                if (list.size() == 0) {
                    placesList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    error_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    error_text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.error_message_color));
                } else {
                    placesList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    error_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                mPlaceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                mAdapter = new PlaceListAdapter(NearByPlaces.this, mPlaceArrayList, true);
                placesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                mNearByPlace = new NearByPlace();
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
                mNearByPlace.setLatitude(hmPlace.get("lat"));
                mNearByPlace.setLongitude(hmPlace.get("lng"));
                mNearByPlace.setName(hmPlace.get("place_name"));
                mNearByPlace.setVicinity(hmPlace.get("vicinity"));
                mPlaceArrayList.add(mNearByPlace);

            }
            mAdapter.setPlaceArrayList(mPlaceArrayList);
        }

    }
```

and NearByPlace is

```
public class NearByPlace {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String vicinity;
    private String placeIcon;

    public NearByPlace(){}

    public String getPlaceIcon() {
        return placeIcon;
    }

    public void setPlaceIcon(String placeIcon) {
        this.placeIcon = placeIcon;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {

        return vicinity;
    }

    public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {

        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {

        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getAddress() {

        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you and you can resolve the minor errors in coz i copied and pasted code from one of my project..